# Most efficient library/framework/method for manipulating large numbers of canvas objects

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a project that makes heavy use of the HTML5 Canvas.  The canvas can have a varying height/width, but for the sake of argument, let's say it's 512x512px.  The canvas is split into a grid, with each cell being 8 pixels.  That's a total of 4096 potential cells for this grid (and the grid can be larger, as large as 1024x1024pixels).

Each grid cell can have it's own colour, as well as mouse events.  I've implemented the basic functionality in three different libraries.  First was raw canvas, second was [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/), and the third was [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS).  All three began to struggle with FPS issues once there were >2000 items on the canvas.

Are there any libraries or tools out there that can help specifically with canvas performance issues that arise from large numbers of objects/draws?  Are there any tutorials (for raw canvas, or using libraries) that touch on this topic?

Comment: I personally like Pixi.js ( http://pixijs.com/ ). It also has a WebGL renderer which improves performance a lot if the device supports it.

Comment: You should listen to what markE is saying. I have my own canvas engine that I use for stuff like this, and I tested it just to compare numbers. Drawing 4096 same colored boxes on a screen I could get 19-22fps in chrome on an older machine. Drawing 4096 different colored boxes got me around 12fps. If you do the equivalent of caching the canvas (markE's hint#1) I get 60fps easily because it's really only drawing 1 image. If you then clearRect on the boxes that change and redraw those you should still be in the 60fps range because I can't see you needing to change too many boxes.

Comment: Similarly, using spritesheets instead of individual images will be much more performant. If you are using vectors, cache them. EaselJS has a SpriteSheetBuilder to generate run-time spritesheets from other content.

Answer (score 2):

If you want good performance with thousands of cells, I would go with raw canvas.

Libraries are great but *they handle eventing & drawing for you at the cost of performance*.

**Design hint #1:**

If a relatively small number of cells are affected by an event, just update & redraw the affected cells rather than clearing the canvas and redrawing every cell.

**Design hint #2:**

Don't try to make all 4096+ cells be "smart" (no handling their own events). Instead:

- Create 4096+ cell objects.
- Listen for [mousedown, mousemove, mouseup] on the canvas and then use the mouse position to determine which cell the mouse is over.
- Make any desired changes to the appropriate cell's properties.

**Design hint #3:**

Separate the mouse events from the drawing.

- Eventing: Save the desired cell related events in an array rather than trying to change the cell properties inside an event handler.
- Use an independent `requestAnimationFrame` loop to do any drawing resulting from the cell related events.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "cache" functionality in easeljs ?http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/Cache.html

If you draw a shape, or use a container object in EaselJS, just add

```
shape.cache(startX, startY, width, height);
```

What this does is it copies a rectangular area of the canvas from (startX, startY) to (startX + width, startY + height) onto an external canvas, and during every redraw, just copies the pixel array back. This enhances performance a lot. You can even apply transforms to this. But if you change the shape or the contents of the container, you have to update the cache. Therefore, this works best for unchanging content.